# find sister element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="videoItem">
    <div class="innerVideoItem">
         <a><div class="overlayBg"></div></a>
         <a><img class="overlayPlay"><img></a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(".overlayPlay").hover(function(){
          // How do I find overlayBg here?
    });
</script>
```

How do I get access to .overlayBg without using `$(".overlayBg")`?

Comment: Without using the `.overlayBg` selector at all? Or just without using that as the initial selector?

Comment: @DavidThomas initial selector, lol

Comment: That really doesn't answer the question I asked, but fair enough: if it's been answered, I'd go with that answer. Best of luck!

Comment: @DavidThomas Also thanks to you dude. Your kindness is heart-warming. (no homo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your markup `overlayBg` and `overlayPlay` are not siblings, they are cousins, you can use `closest` and `find` methods.

```
$(".overlayPlay").hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('.innerVideoItem').find('.overlayBg');
    // $(this).parent().prev().find('.overlayBg')
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude you were quick :)

Answer (score 1):

In native javascript the way to get the previous element is (within your event handler):

```
this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild
```

Answer (score 1):

do you mean:

```
 $(".overlayPlay").hover(function(){
      $(this).parents("div.innerVideoItem").find("div.overlayBg");
 });
```